# How come my sound won't work on Lenovo ThinkPad x230?

Tags: sound, alsa, lenovo, soundcard

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad x230 that I just purchased and installed Ubuntu 12.10 on it. There is no sound, how do I fix it?

I checked that my volume is not muted. I also tried checking in alsamixer and it looks like it doesn't see my sound card.

Comment: I just installed the 3.6.2 kernel to see if it would help, and I had sound for like the first 15 seconds after boot, but after that the sound was gone (even after reboot)

Comment: In my case it helped to use `pavucontrol` (nor `aumix` neither `alsamixer` helped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my X230 Tablet disabling "auto-mute" in alsa-mixer fixes the problem, that there is no sound after one sound was played. Try to plug in headphones and check if there is sound, then it could be the same problem.

Comment: Thank you, disabling auto mute worked for me too. I'm not sure how to submit a bug, but this seems like one worth submitting.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the above works try using

```
alsactl init
```

then play something.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with a similar model thinkpad (x200t) but the solution was easier than I first thought.

I had found that I had pressed the mute button on the keyboard which despite what I tried to do using software wise would not work again until I pressed the  the volume up/down key on the keyboard then the sound was back again.

So, I learnt that I can mute the sound using the hardware button, but cannot turn the sound back on again using the software mixer nor by pressing the mute button again. Only by using the hardware volume buttons on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solved that problem on my x230.

1. Switch to terminal mode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.
2. Stop the display manager LightDM with: `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. Reload ALSA with: `sudo alsa reload`
4. Then restart LightDM with: `sudo service lightdm start`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to select the Multistream mode from Realtek control panel, Device advanced settings
this works for me.

the solution is stolen from this link:
http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/X230-No-Sound-Until-I-Go-To-Settings-To-Play-Sound/td-p/910343

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, the mute button on keyboard stopped working and I couldn't hear anything through settings, it just reverted to mute. 
TO SOLVE: Continue to press the - sound key on the keyboard. Then increase again using the + on the keyboard. It resets, hey presto!!!